# Gigya in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies, mobile-development, gigya

I am trying to implement Gigya signup using credentials and forgetPassword in Flutter. I am getting this,

> 400106    Not connected   User is not connected to the required network or to any network.

error code and description when I am trying to call `gigya.register(..)` via gigya_flutter_plugin ^0.1.6 version.

How to resolve this error?

Also I am not able to initialize gigya using 1.0.0 version. I have followed step by step guide given on [SAP/gigya-flutter-plugin](https://github.com/SAP/gigya-flutter-plugin). Any implemented working code in flutter using 1.0.0 will also be helpful.

Also using example app provided on flutter plugin repo is also giving null error on Signup using credential. Sending parameter in gigya_flutter_plugin ^0.1.6.

```dart
Map<String,dynamic>();
profile["${FIRST_NAME_KEY}"] = 'Harsh';
profile["${COUNTRY_KEY}"] = COUNTRY_VALUE;

final temp = Map<String,dynamic>();
temp["${NUMBER_KEY}"] = '9********0';

profile["${PHONE_KEY}"] = temp;

param["${PROFILE_KEY}"] = profile;

final finalparam = HashMap<String,dynamic>();
finalparam["${PROFILE_KEY}"] = profile;

response = await gigya.register(
'hars*******@gmail.com',
'Password@1234', params: finalparam);
```

Implementing Register Gigya functionality in flutter.